# AddRange not adding in order listed

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I am populating my database with test data and in particular the client table.

I've noticed, once I run the project and when it detects the client table is empty it will use AddRange in an initializer routine to add a 100 clients.

To my surprise I've noticed that the way the system has added each of the 100 clients is out of order to the way its listed in the routine.

This is how its written in the initializer method.

```
context.Clients.AddRange(
    new Client { ABN = "", Active = true, Activity = true, BankAccount = "4308342999", BankBSB = "083-860", BankName = "NAB", ClientFirstName = "Christine", ClientLastName = "Green", ClientNo = 1001, Company = false, CompanyName = "", CreatorId = 1, DateCreated = new DateTime(2016, 02, 14), Email = "cgreen0@google.com.hk", MobilePhone = "0453439816", Phone = "354492968", Postcode = "3555", StateId = 2, Street1 = "01 Clemons Lane", Suburb = "Kangaroo Flat" },
    new Client { ABN = "", Active = true, Activity = true, BankAccount = "5282113099", BankBSB = "012-857", BankName = "ANZ", ClientFirstName = "Jacqueline", ClientLastName = "Porter", ClientNo = 1002, Company = false, CompanyName = "", CreatorId = 1, DateCreated = new DateTime(2016, 02, 14), Email = "jporter1@prweb.com", MobilePhone = "0454972251", Phone = "354400440", Postcode = "3550", StateId = 2, Street1 = "336 Paget Crossing", Suburb = "Bendigo" },
    new Client { ABN = "", Active = true, Activity = true, BankAccount = "6845784050", BankBSB = "083-625", BankName = "NAB", ClientFirstName = "Norma", ClientLastName = "Alvarez", ClientNo = 1003, Company = false, CompanyName = "", CreatorId = 1, DateCreated = new DateTime(2016, 02, 18), Email = "nalvarez2@telegraph.co.uk", MobilePhone = "0418263652", Phone = "354415087", Postcode = "3556", StateId = 2, Street1 = "9418 Ridge Oak Junction", Suburb = "Eaglenhawk" },.......
```

Note that ClientNo starts with 1000 and increments. However, when I examine the database table's data I get this..

```
id ABN Active Activity BankAccount BankBSB BankName ClientFirstName     ClientLastName ClientNo Company CompanyName CreatorId   DateCreated Email   MobilePhone Phone   Postcode    StateId Street1 Suburb              
1       True    True    4308342999  083-860 NAB Christine Green 1001    False       1   14/02/2016 12:00:00 AM  1/01/0001 12:00:00 AM   1/01/0001 12:00:00 AM   cgreen0@google.com.hk   0453439816  NULL    354492968   3555    2   01 Clemons Lane NULL    Kangaroo Flat
2       True    True    1012236821  012-185 ANZ Patrick Rose    1073    False       1   2/10/2016 12:00:00 AM   1/01/0001 12:00:00 AM   1/01/0001 12:00:00 AM   prose20@si.edu  0427959397  NULL    354416917   3556    2   3 Westport Crossing NULL    Eaglenhawk
3       True    True    9680901595  083-185 NAB Joan    Perry   1072    False       1   23/09/2016 12:00:00 AM  1/01/0001 12:00:00 AM   1/01/0001 12:00:00 AM   jperry1z@wsj.com    0445920808  NULL    354444482   3550    2   65944 Westport Crossing NULL    Bendigo
```

ClientNo stated with 1000 as part of the add range and every client incremented by one however you can see that the system added each record in a different order.

How can I make AddRange add the records in the order they appear in the list?

Comment: Please don't force tags into the title :) http://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging It's sufficient to add the tag in the tag section

Answer (score 0):

You could always just add the range to a list and order the list like:

```
var clientList = new List<Client>();
clientList.AddRange(
        new Client { ABN = "", Active = true, Activity = true, BankAccount = "4308342999", BankBSB = "083-860", BankName = "NAB", ClientFirstName = "Christine", ClientLastName = "Green", ClientNo = 1001, Company = false, CompanyName = "", CreatorId = 1, DateCreated = new DateTime(2016, 02, 14), Email = "cgreen0@google.com.hk", MobilePhone = "0453439816", Phone = "354492968", Postcode = "3555", StateId = 2, Street1 = "01 Clemons Lane", Suburb = "Kangaroo Flat" },
        new Client { ABN = "", Active = true, Activity = true, BankAccount = "5282113099", BankBSB = "012-857", BankName = "ANZ", ClientFirstName = "Jacqueline", ClientLastName = "Porter", ClientNo = 1002, Company = false, CompanyName = "", CreatorId = 1, DateCreated = new DateTime(2016, 02, 14), Email = "jporter1@prweb.com", MobilePhone = "0454972251", Phone = "354400440", Postcode = "3550", StateId = 2, Street1 = "336 Paget Crossing", Suburb = "Bendigo" },
        new Client { ABN = "", Active = true, Activity = true, BankAccount = "6845784050", BankBSB = "083-625", BankName = "NAB", ClientFirstName = "Norma", ClientLastName = "Alvarez", ClientNo = 1003, Company = false, CompanyName = "", CreatorId = 1, DateCreated = new DateTime(2016, 02, 18), Email = "nalvarez2@telegraph.co.uk", MobilePhone = "0418263652", Phone = "354415087", Postcode = "3556", StateId = 2, Street1 = "9418 Ridge Oak Junction", Suburb = "Eaglenhawk" });

context.Clients.AddRange(clientList.OrderBy(c => c.ClientNo))
```